# Behavior of lambda in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I have a class with an enumerator:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    enum enTest
    {
        TestA,
        TestB,
        TestC
    };

    void foo(); 
}
```

and inside my foo function:

```
void MyClass::foo()
{
    MyClass::enTest var = MyClass::TestA;

    auto lambda = [&] () -> void
    {
        if (var == MyClass::TestA)
            int x = 3;
    };
}
```

and it gives me the error:
error C2227: left of '->TestA' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

in the 'if' line but if i change the capture of the lambda to [&var] it works.

Why?

I thought that [&] capture any referenced variable by reference.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Works fine in GCC. MSVC bug ?

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) articles. Capture groups in C++11 lambdas are madness, study them well before any attempt of usage or you'll be damned my friend.

Comment: I dont know, i'm using VS10!

Comment: @LiquidPenguin MSVS 2010 has abysmal C++11 support.  I would suggest upgrading to 2015 if you can.

Comment: @LiquidPenguin: This is probably an odd VC-2010 bug.

Comment: First, you don't need to prefix `enTest` and `TestA` with `MyClass::` inside `MyClass::foo()` because it is MyClass's member function. Second, on what line is that compiler error given?

Comment: @mvidelgauz in the 'if' line